# SAS -- Collapse data by date with duplicate unique IDs

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS and am struggling to find the best method to collapse a dataset that has numerous observations for the same date, with duplicate unique IDs. 
An  example of the data looks like:

```
ENROLID     date        AGE  
763942001   8/21/2015   56  
763942001   8/21/2015   56  
770246102   8/21/2015   38  
30738958501 9/30/2015   46  
30881826801 9/30/2015   36  
30881826801 9/30/2015   36  
30881826801 9/30/2015   36  
30881826801 9/30/2015   36
```

I'd like to have a dataset organized like a time series, where each row is the date. Since there are duplicates of unique ids on a specific date, how can I count them as only being one observation on that date? Ultimately, I want total count of unique ids by each day, without double counting.

Comment: As posted this does not meet a SO question rules. Please post the code you've tried so far, explain how it doesn't work and review the guidelines on how to ask a good question.  What you're looking for is a count distinct which is usually accomplished via SQL or PROC FREQ.

Comment: The `nodupkey` option in proc sort will probably handle this.

Comment: https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/count_distinct_by_group